# buttons that don't submit in rails, and dealing with f.select in controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Update:  I forgot about the type="button", this has been updated.  My buttons still fail and I think that is because when I was testing I was using `select_tag` then in trying to get that to work on the controller side, I switched it to `f.select` in a form for, in which case now my javascript does not work properly.  I am guessing because the f.select makes the object something different.  My question now is should I use a form_for f.select or the select_tag?  I am not overly sure on the difference (I am guessing the form_for f.select gives me some automagicness with the model passed in).  Can I still consume the object on the controller if i used the select_tag?  I really have no idea what param map this is coming back in in either case.  Also if the `f.select` is the preferred method then I will adjust my javascript accordingly.

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

            $('.add').on('click', function() {
                var options = $('select#group_providers option:selected').sort().clone();
                $('select#provider_locations').append(options);
            });
            $('.addAll').on('click', function() {
                var options = $('select#group_providers option').sort().clone();
                $('select#provider_locations').append(options);
            });
            $('.remove').on('click', function() {
                $('select#provider_locations option:selected').remove();
            });
            $('.removeAll').on('click', function() {
                $('select#provider_locations').empty();
            });

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

I have some java script handling two multiple select boxes.  [image]

I want my remove, remove all to not submit the form.  They seem to automatically do that.  If I leave out the form_for at the top of my form then these buttons do the java script that they are supposed to do...   or if I use this code i found on the blog here:

`http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=259`

Then sure it doesn't submit but the javascript doesn't work either.

Secondly I also had these as select_tags and then moved them under the form_for.  It really boggles my mind how to deal with the data in that left column coming back in the controller, also this form is called from an add_locations action in the controller.   Is it kosher that the submit that happens calls an update action again, or would I want to call a different action to handle the data (Me thinks so) that action I can pass into the form_for as well?  (Code follows)  This is confusing me cause the models I have here are pretty deep in associations.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <%= form_for (@provider) do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>            
                  <h3> <%= @provider.last_name %> , <%= @provider.first_name %> 's Locations</h3>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>          
                 <% if @provider.provider_locations.count >0 %>
                    <%= f.select "provider_locations", options_from_collection_for_select(@provider.provider_locations.map{|j| j.group_location}, :id , :dba), {}, {:multiple => elseb} %>
                  <% true %>
                    <%= f.select "provider_locations", "<option></option>".html_safe, :multiple => true, :style => "width: 300px" %>       
                  <% end %>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>          
                   <!-- <button class="remove">Remove</button>  -->
                   <%= submit_tag 'Remove it', :type => 'button', :class => 'remove' %>

                </td>
                <td>          
                  <!-- button class="removeAll">Remove All</button -->
                  <%= submit_tag 'Remove All', :type => 'button', :class => 'removeAll' %>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>         
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <table>
              <tr>
                <th>            <!-- maybe some buttons here -->

                </th>
              </tr>                   
            </table>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>            
                 <h3> All Group Locations </h3> <!-- might need a search here too -->
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>          
                  <% if @group_locations.count >0 %>
                    <%= select_tag "group_providers", options_from_collection_for_select(GroupLocation.all, :id , :dba), :multiple => true %>
                  <% else %>
                    <%= select_tag "group_providers", "<option>Add new...</option>".html_safe, :multiple => true, :style => "width: 300px" %>       
                  <% end %>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>          
                    <button class="add">Add</button>

                </td>
                <td>          
                    <button class="addAll">Add All</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>        
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the buttons, just use an `a` tag and style it as a button or you can explicitly set the button's `type` to `button` as the default type is `submit` which will trigger submitting the form.

Comment: that did it thanks.  The buttons still fail and I think it is because I have them in the form_for (so it doesn't find the provider_locations select anymore.  I guess the form_for changes things so I am adding that to my question.